Solving for  in a Recursive Sum Constraint
Given a positive integer $n$, let $S(n)$ be the sum of the digits of $n$ in its decimal representation. Determine all positive integers  $n$ such that:
$n+S(n)+S(S(n))=1000$
My approach:$S(n)$ is the sum of the digits of
$n$, which means $S(n)$ is always less than or equal to the number of digits in $n$ times $9$. For example, if $n$ is a $3$-digit number, then  $S(n) \le 27$.
